# How to return Java.Lang.Object from a overridden method in MonoDroid

Tags: c#, java, android, xamarin.android

How do you do the following i MonoDroid?

```
public class ItemListAdapter : BaseAdapter    
{
    IEnumerable<Item> items;

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
            {
                items.ElementAt(position);
            }
}
```

The problem is that I need to override the `GetItem()` because I subclass the `BaseAdapter`, but obviously the above causes compiler error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make "Item" be a subclass of Java.Lang.Object.

Answer (score 1):

items.ElementAt(position).JavaCast< Java.Lang.Object >();